# viewDidLayoutSubviews is called when label changes (xcode) (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uilabel, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a label, toggle button and an animation in my code. When I press the toggle button -> animation starts , label changes. Below is my code sample.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
println("viewDidLayoutSubviews is called")
// Initial state of my animation.
     }

 @IBAction func Toggled(sender: AnyObject) {
    CallTextChange() 
   // Two different Animations        
     }

 func CallTextChange() { // Change text here}
```

Every time I change the text in label viewDidLayoutSubviews is called. 
Is there a way to stop calling it every time I change the label?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my problem.

When we create UIImage by drag and dropping from the object provided by Xcode, the image is temporary placed where it was statically placed. So when animating in middle when viewDidLayoutSubviews is called the image is placed in the static place.
So the UIImage has to be created programmatically.

```
CreateImage.image = UIImage(named: "Image.png")
CreateImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CreateImage.image!.size.width/6, height: CreateImage.image!.size.height/6))
self.view.addSubview(CreateImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass one boolean flag values in function

Answer (score 0):

I think when you change text of and UILabel it will change its intrinsic content size that in turn will notify the system to relayout the view hierarchy. So it seems inevitable that viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called.

Either you put a boolean flag to make your initial animation code execute once only or move your code to other place like viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Thanks guys for your advice, I tried it. But no matter what if i change the text the viewDidLayoutSubviews is called and the suddenly the animation goes to its initial position and then continues the that animation. Please tell me how to stop calling the viewDidLayoutSubviews function automatically if the label is changed.

Comment: As the answer suggest there is no way to stop is being called if you change label text. You should put some flag that will stop your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews() execute only once.