# Swift: What is the meaning of viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, swift

I have code under `viewDidLayoutSubviews` with intention of making an image transparent (alpha = 0) in the beginning which slowly fades in (into alpha = 1) with code under `viewDidAppear`. Also, I have a button which changes it's own label text when pressed.

However, when the button is pressed and the label changes, the image (which I've specified under `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) also disappears. Which I think is because the code under `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called?

My question is:

**1)** What is the meaning of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Why is it called when the button label changes? Just briefly/generally, what is `setNeedsLayout` & `setNeedsDisplayInRect`?

**2)** Is it better to use viewWillAppear then?

Here are 2 similar questions but I couldn't understand enough from them:

1) [viewDidLayoutSubviews is called when label changes (xcode) (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253549/viewdidlayoutsubviews-is-called-when-label-changes-xcode-swift)

2) [Why viewdidlayoutsubviews call multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014360/why-viewdidlayoutsubviews-call-multiple-times)

Answer (score 9):

As name suggests, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called when the view of your `viewController` has just finished its laying out and you can assume that at that point your views are in their correct places/`frame`s according to your `autolayout` constraints. You shouldn't perform any action assuming your `view`s have their final `frame`s before that method is called: for example, if you try to `aView setFrame:` in your `viewDidLoad` it will probably fail/have no effect as `autolayout` changes its `frame` during laying out phase. Therefore, if you really need to change its frame, you should call `setFrame:` in/after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

In short, if your concern is about alpha value of an `image` or `imageView`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is probably not the correct place. `viewDidAppear` seems to be more appropriate for this. `viewDidAppear` is pretty straighforward: when the view appears on the screen, it is called.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to read the docs? [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews), [setNeedsLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsLayout) etc?

Button label change -> width change -> rearrange -> `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
You should not treat `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as a single call event. You should start an image transparency animation in `viewDidAppear` with `UIView.animateWithDuration`, it is a good place to start it, since everything is aligned properly. Let the image alpha be 0 in IB or init method and then just animate it.

Comment: I would like to invite you to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678975/need-assistance-regarding-viewdidlayoutsubviews

Comment: _"You should not treat viewDidLayoutSubviews as a single call"_ - This is critical.